# How is the artwork at Adobe.com created?

Tags: adobe-creative-suite

Having finally signed up to creative cloud, which seems incredibly good value, I started to wander how the artwork Adobe use to promote their products is actually made... Its quite 3D, and looks very slick (see http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4TQFdMFdN40J:www.adobe.com/uk/products/creativesuite.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk)

[image]

I am specifically referring to the 3D "Rods" that seem to be bursting out from a point.

Would I be correct in thinking that (ironically) these are not made in any of the creative suite applications? I know PS and AI have basic 3D capability, but these look to be beyond those capabilities to me....

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: works fine for me - try http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/creativesuite.edu.html

Comment: Ah, I see what's the problem is. Adobe's website automatically redirect the query to the SEA website, which doesn't have the same UK page. Their change location dialog doesn't work, so I can't access at the page directly. Most likely your link will work fine for UK members and 404 for everybody else. Fortunately, Google cache doesn't care where I am so this works: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4TQFdMFdN40J:www.adobe.com/uk/products/creativesuite.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you're right. Looks like they've used a 3D app to build at least the underlying image.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for the alternative link, i have edited the original question to include.
@MarcEdwards - yes thats what I thought (although we may be proven wrong) seems a bit like false advertising tbh!!!

Comment: Could it have involved After Effects? I don't use AE myself but I know some people use it alongside PS/AI etc to create static stills, and I'm pretty sure you can use it to create effects like that: e.g. http://greyscalegorilla.com/blog/2010/04/reflective-and-refractive-glass-block-tutorial-part-2-after-effects/

Comment: I particularly thought of AE because of the volume of shapes with potentially formula-driven effects applied - made me think of some of the things people do with AE particles (e.g http://www.jinghaiyu.net/after-effects/5232-videohive-transformation-of-particles-492533.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be make this using a 3D app which support (directly or by plugin) populating an object (the rod in this case) onto another object <strike>(f.ex a ball object)</strike> like a flat surface with a wide-angle camera. There is absolutely no need to use fractals, displacement and so forth.

I setup this scene in about 3 minutes in Vue Infinite just for the sake of demo (further light and camera adjustments ans so forth would make it more identical):

[image: Rods rendered in Vue]

You can download a free version of Vue Pioneer here:
[Vue Free version](http://www.cornucopia3d.com/products/vue/vue_2014_pioneer/?page=download)

(I am using Vue 10 Infinite - I am not sure if the free version supports population, you will need to check out the different versions at [E-onsoftware](http://www.e-onsoftware.com/))

I am also willing to share the file I used here if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

i believe what they've done is modeled the heart like shape in 3d as well as all the bars and squares exploding out.

They've then taken this model into a 3d rendering program and colored it and added the translucency into the shapes.

Finaly it would have been brought into Photoshop where the background, the faces, star bursts and all post processing colour work would have been done.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using fractals (quite tediously though).Although you may very well be right to think that there is a 3D app behind the underlying graphics)

But again i think this not an easy design to replicate even by using [photoshop's capabilities to generate fractals](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tutorials-effects/how-to-simulate-fractals-in-photoshop/), **because replicating fractals is essentially harder than making one yourself**.

I'm thinking a lot of layers would have to be used for the different the bars which seem to be coming out of the center (i guess one would just have to make at least one instance of each bar manually ) then using the fractal simulating technique **( <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> `>>followed by>>` *desired transformation* `>>followed by>>` <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+T</kbd>(many times until you get the fractal you want) )** and figuring out the placement of the transform center, one maybe able to generate the desired fractal.

Check out [this fractal art work](http://xyrus02.deviantart.com/) and [tutorial](http://xyrus02.deviantart.com/art/Making-of-WHWF-262881512) on making fractal art.